# TypeORM CLI - How to run MIGRATIONS on a SPECIFIC DATABASE

Tags: postgresql, orm, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

My `ormconfig.json` has multiple DBs, how to run migrations for a **SPECIFIC DB** of this list? In the example below I have the `dev` db with migrations already set, now I need to set migrations for the other db called `test`.

I wanted to run a command like this:

> `yarn typeorm migration:run --database test`

```json
// ormconfig.json

[
  {
    "name": "dev",
    "type": "postgres",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 5432,
    "username": "postgres",
    "password": "postgres",
    "database": "postgres",
    "synchronize": true,
    "logging": true,
    "entities": ["src/typeorm/entity/**/*.ts"],
    "migrations": ["src/typeorm/migration/**/*.ts"],
    "subscribers": ["src/typeorm/subscriber/**/*.ts"],
    "cli": {
      "entitiesDir": "src/typeorm/entity",
      "migrationsDir": "src/typeorm/migration",
      "subscribersDir": "src/typeorm/subscriber"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "test",
    "type": "postgres",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 5433,
    "username": "postgres",
    "password": "postgres",
    "database": "postgres",
    "synchronize": true,
    "logging": false,
    "entities": ["src/typeorm/entity/**/*.ts"],
    "migrations": ["src/typeorm/migration/**/*.ts"],
    "subscribers": ["src/typeorm/subscriber/**/*.ts"],
    "cli": {
      "entitiesDir": "src/typeorm/entity",
      "migrationsDir": "src/typeorm/migration",
      "subscribersDir": "src/typeorm/subscriber"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run:

`yarn typeorm migration:run -c configName` where configName is the `name` of the configuration in your `ormconfig.json` db list.